# htaccess redirection Rewriterule issue page errors

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need a help in the htacceess stuff.  I have to avoid page errors occurring when some one try to enter incorrect urls of my site. what exactly I'm looking is that I need a htaccess code to redirect the invalid entries with terms to existing correct urls.

some thing like this:

```
Rewriterule ^(.*)\term\*$ http://www.term.com/*$1 [r=301,nc]
```

The above code is definitely wrong, I don't know if any other code extra needed with that (`Options +FollowSymlinks` so and so..).
anybody could help me to sort out this, please..?

Comment: Can't you just use `ErrorDocument 404 /`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a redirect rule for this purpose. Configure a 404 error document as given below

```
ErrorDocument 404     /404.html
```

Don't forget to create 404.html to serve good looking screen to user.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
But I need the Rewriterule code itself.. for particular purpose, plus if someone could give a best htaccess tutorial link.. thats also great..